# Adding JS files to list of excepted files for forms authentication in web.config causes infinite redirect

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, web-config

I want to add a JS file to the login page. So include the file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Functions/AppLocation.js"></script>
```

and in the web.config:

```
<location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

But when I direct to the login page which is:

```
http://localhost:21206/en-GB/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f
```

it does a redirect loop on a url that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:21206/en-GB/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fen-GB%2f%5bobject+Object%5d
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the framework is trying to go to the login page but it is redirect due to insufficient privileges. Have you made sure that your login page does not require authentication? That will surely cause it to go to in an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi, If I remove the Js include file, the redirect does not occur.

Comment: Can you try and specify the path as "Scripts/Functions" ?